# Why will my text not align properly inside my <li> element?

Tags: css, html-lists, alignment

I Have been fiddling with this for hours. I can not get my text to align vertically within the  25px a element. The text always wants to sit at the every top of the coloured 'box'. I just want it in the vertical middle. Additionally this problem is being inherited throughout all of my list.

```css
#nav ul li.cat:nth-child(1) > a {
    background-color: #647484;
}

#nav ul li a {
    color: #FFFF00;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1em;
    height: 25px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 137px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="nav">
<ul>
<li class="cat">
<a href="http://localhost/country/index.php/welcome/cat/19">Beef</a>
<ul>
<li class="subcat">
<a href="http://localhost/country/index.php/welcome/cat/21">Ribs</a>
</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li class="subcat">
<a href="http://localhost/country/index.php/welcome/cat/30">Steaks </a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="cat">
<a href="http://localhost/country/index.php/welcome/cat/19">Beef</a>
<ul>
<li class="subcat">
<a href="http://localhost/country/index.php/welcome/cat/21">Ribs</a>
</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li class="subcat">
<a href="http://localhost/country/index.php/welcome/cat/30">Steaks </a>
</li>
</ul>
</li> <!-- etc etc -->
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: at least paste them correct so we can test it in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line-height is less than the height of your box, so it looks like it aligns to the top when it's actually just taking up the space it should. Try setting `line-height: 25px` along with your height.

[See the jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/c5gGj/4/)

Comment: That is Mega ! Thank you !! One small additional problem ... I want the height of the smaller sub categories to be smaller than the main categories. The sub categories are in fact inheriting the height of the Main - any advice on how to fix that too ? Many Many Thanks !

Comment: @VinceJacobs: Just add another selector below that to grab anchors inside a "subcat" list item: http://jsfiddle.net/c5gGj/5/ - See `#nav ul li.subcat a`.

Comment: Hi animuson - Many thanks ! I'm still getting something weird. When I apply the line height as recommended my main categories are coming out vertically aligned inside fiddle with the sub categories coming out of vertical alignment. However, when tested inside FF the opposite happens ie the subs are perfect and the Main cats are pushed up. I have posted my html and css here: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vincej/hVDe9/)

Comment: @VinceJacobs: That's because you're setting the physical height of the list item to 15px in `#nav ul li.subcat`, but you're setting the height and line-height of the anchor to 20px in that new rule. You should either change the [20px to 15px](http://jsfiddle.net/2MRMN/) or the [15px to 20px](http://jsfiddle.net/mrHMd/). If you want my opinion, the 15px version looks a tad too crunched together.

Comment: Once again - Thank you very very much ! I thought I knew css ! I like this fiddle thing - never seen it before. Cheers from Canada !

Comment: @VinceJacobs: Remember to mark the answer as accepted (the check mark at the left) when it solves your problem.